# db4o to preserve identity of objects

Tags: java, db4o

Is there a way to preserve an object identity in db4o.

Suppose I store a BigDecimal in embedded db4o.

When I read it twice I get two distinct objects with the same value (which is quite obvious).

Is there any setting to force db4o to cache query results so that two queries would return reference to the same instance, or do I have to do it myself ?

Comment: did you ever find an answer to this?

Comment: No i did not. I changed a storage mechanizm from embedded db4o to XStrem.

Answer (score 1):

From my experience, running the same query twice on the same ObjectContainer should return the same (identical) objects each time.

You should not close and reopen the ObjectContainer between the queries, if you need the objects' identity.

Answer (score 0):

Db4o does use [IDs and UUIDs](http://developer.db4o.com/Resources/view.aspx/Reference/Implementation_Strategies/IDs_and_UUIDs) internally and you can access those if needed. Also worth reading is [this](http://developer.db4o.com/Resources/view.aspx/Reference/Basic_Concepts/Object_Identity/Unique_Identity_Concept).

Comment: I think this is a valid link: http://developer.db4o.com/Documentation/Reference/db4o-7.4/java/reference/html/reference/implementation_strategies/ids_and_uuids.html

Answer (score 0):

you can make an id for each object of yours by using it's UUIDs, I mean add an attribute ID for the object and give it UUIDs value and store it, to update an object you can retrieve it by that Id and update it